# Extract text from a variable in a dataframe and create new vectors

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a database which comes from a questionnaire. This database has some complicated and long text, which for my purposes I also have to use them as a variables later on my analysis.

An example of the dataframe type I analyse is as the following one:

```
cnt  <-as.factor(c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3" ))
bnk  <-as.factor(c("bank 1", "bank 2", "bank 3", "bank 1", "bank 2", "bank 3" ))
qst  <-as.factor(c(" Q.1 - some long question?", " Q.1 - some long question?", " Q.1 - some long question?", "Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?","Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?","Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?" ))
ans  <-as.numeric(c(1,1,2,1,2,3))
df   <-data.frame(cnt, bnk, qst,ans)
names(df) <- c("Country", "Institute", "Question", "Answer")
head(df)

  Country Institute                             Question Answer
1 Country 1    bank 1            Q.1 - some long question?      1
2 Country 2    bank 2            Q.1 - some long question?      1
3 Country 3    bank 3            Q.1 - some long question?      2
4 Country 1    bank 1 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      1
5 Country 2    bank 2 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      2
6 Country 3    bank 3 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      3
```

As you can see in the variable "Question", no matter what the question is, there is a pattern: All text starts with Q.number

Just for your information, the numbers of different questions are 49.

There are a couple of things (or steps) that I want to do here:

1. first, I want to create new vector that I can indexes the question. So, for example my dataframe to become like this:

df<-mutate(df, qs=c("q1","q1","q1", "q27","q27","q27" ))

```
  Country Institute                             Question Answer qs
1 Country 1    bank 1            Q.1 - some long question?      1 q1
2 Country 2    bank 2            Q.1 - some long question?      1 q1
3 Country 3    bank 3            Q.1 - some long question?      2 q1
4 Country 1    bank 1 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      1 q27
5 Country 2    bank 2 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      2 q27
6 Country 3    bank 3 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      3 q27
```

2. Then, I want to create a new vector similar to the one is step 1, but the indexation includes numbers only. This is because I want to treat this additional vector as factor where I want to use as labels the part of each question that does not include the "Q.". For this purpose, I guess I need to search in the variable "Question" and make the relevant extraction.

Ultimately, therefore, the data frame must look something like this:

```
Country Institute                             Question Answer qs qs_inx                 labels
1 Country 1    bank 1            Q.1 - some long question?      1 q1      1   some long question? 
2 Country 2    bank 2            Q.1 - some long question?      1 q1      1    some long question?
3 Country 3    bank 3            Q.1 - some long question?      2 q1      1    some long question?
4 Country 1    bank 1 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      1 q2      2 another long question?
5 Country 2    bank 2 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      2 q2      2 another long question?
6 Country 3    bank 3 Q.27 <U+FFFD> another long question?      3 q2      2 another long question?
```

Comment: Use `sub`, like `df %>% mutate(qs_idx = sub('(Q.\\d+).*', '\\1', Question), 
              qs = as.integer(sub('Q.', '', qs_idx)))`. If you like, use `tidyr::extract_numeric` or `stringr::str_extract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand correctly you want two copies of `df$Question`, but using different labels in each copy.

```
df$qs_inx <- df$Question
df$labels <- df$Question

levels(df$qs_inx) <- sub('[ ]*Q\\.([0-9]+).*', 'q\\1', levels(df$Question))
levels(df$labels) <- sub('[ ]*Q\\.(.*)', '\\1', levels(df$Question))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But, can you please provide some explanation for the use of  '[ ]*Q\\.([0-9]+).*', 'q\\1' and '[ ]*Q\\.(.*)', '\\1'. It would be great to know. Otherwise, any reference would be also great.

Comment: @msh855 these are regular expressions https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html